# Sklearn classification with DecisionTree, how to improve fit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

it's the first time i approach data analysis, and i'm trying to perform a classification problem. I'm trying to predict the price of a car. I have the following DataFrame (already cleaned):

```
price   vehicleType yearOfRegistration  gearbox powerPS model   kilometer   fuelType    brand   notRepairedDamage
2   9000    suv 2004    automatik   163 grand   125000  diesel  jeep    not-declared
3   1500    kleinwagen  2001    manuell 75  golf    150000  benzin  volkswagen  nein
4   3000    kleinwagen  2008    manuell 69  fabia   90000   diesel  skoda   nein
6   1500    cabrio  2004    manuell 109 2_reihe 150000  benzin  peugeot nein
8   12500   bus 2014    manuell 125 c_max   30000   benzin  ford    not-declared
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
371520  3000    limousine   2004    manuell 225 leon    150000  benzin  seat    ja
371524  1000    cabrio  2000    automatik   101 fortwo  125000  benzin  smart   nein
371525  9000    bus 1996    manuell 102 transporter 150000  diesel  volkswagen  nein
371526  3000    kombi   2002    manuell 100 golf    150000  diesel  volkswagen  not-declared
371527  25000   limousine   2013    manuell 320 m_reihe 50000   benzin  bmw nein
```

So, as you can see there are categorical atributes. Therefore I have to encode them. I did it this way:

```
encoding = DataFrameMapper([
    (['vehicleType', 'gearbox', 'model', 'fuelType', 'brand', 'notRepairedDamage'], 
      OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),    
    (["yearOfRegistration", "powerPS", "kilometer"], OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
    ])

encoding_target = DataFrameMapper([
    (['price'], None)
])
```

Here I should mention that I had a column called 'names' with the name and optional of the car. I had to drop that since the dataframe has 250k rows and if I try to encode that column too I get Memory Error.

Then I proceded fitting and transforming:

```
encoding.fit(data)
encoding_target.fit(data)

X = encoding.transform(data.loc[:, data.columns != "price"])
y = encoding_target.transform(data[['price']])
```

Then I created the train/test split

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .2, random_state = 0)
```

and then just called the decision tree constructor as:

```
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = tree.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

I get a score of 0.38. Which is really low. So, I'd like to ask you if the problem is in how I encode the dataframe for using it with sklearn. Is yes, is there a better way? This way I also have problems with cross validation, and I don't feel the dataframe as it is is fully usable with other algorithms. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Price is a continuous variable, and you should use regression instead of classification, where (i.e. in regression) accuracy is meaningless.

Comment: Price is not continuous it is divide in 12 intervals

Comment: If so, you should mention this explicitly in the question. Keep in mind that, this way, you lose ordinality information (i.e. that `'9000'` is less than `'15000'`

Comment: Yeah, i should keep that in mind, but as far as I'm concerned now I'm trying to understand if that .38 is due to the algorithm that is not suited for this or for the way i encoded categoricals

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is an Stackoverflow question instead of stackexchange or science, since it's not programming related. But here are some tips:

1. You don't need to encode your y variable, most sklearn will convert
   it to numbers. If not, just make a set for mapping (if they are
   categorical).
2. It's going to be pretty impossible for an algoritm to
   get a high number as a prediction. Try transforming you y variable
   into something else. (i.e.: Higher or lower than 10k or % increase
   after X periods).
3. When your y-categorical-variable has more than 2
   options, set the "stratify=y" argument at train_test_split)

Your low accuracy is mostly by bullet 2 by the way.

**edit:** Just saw your commend that your y is divided between 12 intervals. So you should do a mix of all tips. Create a new y variable that will be something like `if price between 0 and 1k then 0, elif between 1k and 3k then 1 (and so on..)`, maybe using panda's .loc().

Comment: If i try to use stratify i get an error saying that it has to have at least 2 levels (it was t levels, i dont remember now)

Comment: To stratify it means that for each category it will get values that represent your `test_size` value. If you have only 1 row for a category and you want a test_size of 20%, you can't split that 1 result. So it returns an error. So you need to remake your y variable as in my edit first. (and be sure to have more than 1 result per category). Also if your data is unbalanced, check if your algorithm has the `class_weight` parameter and set it to "balanced".

Comment: So, basically, the way I encoded my y variable is wrong. As you can see i set no transformation, but I also tried with OrdinalEncoder(). There is something that I'm missing here... I feel the experience is missing here on my side..

Comment: I'm not sure OrdinalEncoder should be used for the target variable, as is described to be used for Features (X). Try using `sklearn's LabelEncoder`

Answer (score 1):

If you are predicting the price of a car, `price` is your target feature, so it would normally be a regression problem, not classification. The classification model has no idea 1000 is closer to 1500 than 25000 – it just treats them as separate classes. You're model has an accuracy of 0.38 at predicting the class of price.

Try `DecisionTreeRegressor()` instead. You can look at some of these metrics: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics

Comment: Hello, OP said in his question's comments that it's a categorical (but he didn't change the values to match it yet): `"Price is not continuous it is divide in 12 intervals"`

Comment: But i created 12 intervals for prices, it is not a continuous variable

Comment: Instead of a 12 class classification problem, you can try fewer classes, such as small and large. A high number of classes usually makes things much more difficult. To specifically answer your question about how to improve fit on this model, you can try other encoding techniques (like `OrdinalEncoder()`) or try feature engineering, but I doubt this estimator can be improved much.